# mutable reference while already borrowing immutably while designing an event loop polling system

Tags: rust

I'm trying understand how to create an eventloop in rust, i have the following code, using `mio`:

```
        loop {
            println!("loopieboy");
            self.poll
                .poll(&mut self.events, Some(Duration::from_millis(0)))
                .unwrap();

            let mut on_connected_tokens = Vec::new();
            for event in self.events.iter() {
                if event.token() == Token(0) && event.is_writable() {
                    println!("token 0 is writable");
                    on_connected_tokens.push(event.token());
                }
            }

            for token in on_connected_tokens {
                let handler =  self.handlers.get(&token).unwrap(); 
               handler.as_ref().on_connected(&mut self);
            }

            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100));
        }
```

here a handler is a trait implementing the `on_connected(&self, event_core: &mut EventLoop)`. Where `EventLoop` is my .. well event loop.

The problem is that on the last line with

```
handler.as_ref().on_connected(&mut self);
```

I am trying to borrow mutably, where on line

```
   let handler =  self.handlers.get(&token).unwrap();
```

I am already borrowing immutably. This is not allowed.

My problem here, is that I think i'm trying to project my C++ experience on rust, and its failing. I'd like to do the following:

- have a loop that checks sockets
- any socket that has a respective handler, should get data + the event loop

THe last thing "+ the event loop" exists to not have acyclical dependencies, but I feel that I'm trying to row against the wind.

In short:

- what is the idiomatic way of approaching an event loop, and more importantly, how do i NOT borrow mutably, when I am already borrowing immutably(like in the loop

Comment: Because a mutable reference to the "event loop" is passed to the `on_connected` function, that function could *modify* the set of handlers including the one that is then being called.  It is about this potential problem that Rust is complaining.  I confess I don't understand your requirements well enough to propose a solution: in particular, I don't understand how passing this mutable reference to the "event loop" prevents (a?)cyclical dependencies?

Comment: it doesnt, im trying to figure out how to do it. I want an event loop type system that polls the sockets every cycle and offloads the data if available on to handlers that can process that data and, if needed, put a timer on th event loop (like; fire off in 5 seconds, or send something to a socket)

i feel like i'm rowing against the current here, so i'm looking for the rustic way

Comment: @eggyal what i ended up doing is having a `Rc<RefCall<EventLoop>>` and asking for a mutable borrow everytime its needed.